# Setting static variable from properties in a non-auto-instantiated class

Tags: java, spring-boot, static-variables

I am trying to set a static variable in a *normal* class within a Spring Boot application. By normal class, I mean one that is not instantiated when the application loads (i.e. *not* a @Controller, @Service or other such annotated entity); I will create new instances of this object.

The basic class definintion (setters, getters, functions as required):

```
public class SettingDate {
    private static float yearLength;
    private float absoluteDate;
}
```

The value I want for `yearLength` is defined in `application.properties`. I do not want to hard-code it into the class.

The problem is that everything I have found about setting such a static variable is specific to classes that Spring Boot instantiates. How do I do it cleanly in a non-auto-instantiated class withough the overhead of reading the entire properties file in situ (which would technically mean hard-coding the name of that file)?

*Expanded explanation of use case*

I need to be able to track dates (in an non-Earth setting).

The `SettingDate` objects will be used as elements of other objects, as a `Date` would be. (I am hoping that JPA will be able to map them in and out of the database as only the `absoluteDate` value.)

The `yearLength` value is used by the SettingDate objects to perform date conversions. It belongs to the class, not the objects – it's common throughout the setting – hence is `static`. But I do need to get the value from application.properties into the class.

When the application loads, there is no reason to create an instance of the `SettingDate`. As such, there is no logic in creating a `@Bean` with one.

However, *everything* I have come across about dependency injection is predecated on the creation of beans. Where am I supposed to put a function that a) can take an input from `@Value` and b) runs automatically at application start, which can set `yearLength` from that property?

Comment: If it's not a constant, don't make it `static`. Inject it appropriately (usually as a constructor `@Value` parameter or via an `@Bean` method).

Comment: It is a constant. At least it is constant within any running of the application. I don't need or want an object instantiated as a `@Bean` (that would make no sense), and from what I can make out, `@Value` doesn't work with objects instantiated via `new`.

Comment: If it's not a _constant_, it's not a constant. There are a number of reasons to treat non-constants as non-constants, particularly including dynamic configuration reloads and testing. It smells like you're trying to fight the concept of dependency injection; there are patterns to do the sort of thing you're talking about (e.g., factories), and if you explain your use case further we might be able to recommend a clean approach.

Comment: Use case explanation added.

Comment: The answer is still "don't use a static, use a bean"; the place(s) you are creating new objects should either take a `SettingDate` as a constructor parameter, passed in from an `@Bean` method, or a `SettingDateProvider` (or `Supplier<SettingDate>`, since that's probably not too generic).